# Quarkus REST Client call with generic type

Tags: java, rest, generics, quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

I am using Quarkus REST client (with annotation @RegisterRestClient) to call one of the services. I have implemented a post method in the Rest Client class like below:

```
@POST
Response postData(EmployeeDTO emp)
```

This call works fine when the parameter type is specific. However, this operation can take one of many types of data so the callers have a generic implementation before calling this like below:

```
callingMethod(U request){
   restClient.postData(Entity.json(request))
}
```

For this i tried changing the client to
`restClient.postData(Entity<U>)`

but then the actual call doesn't seem to recognize the actual json and throws the validation failures.

Caused by: javax.json.JsonException: JSON invalid for schema

Any idea how this can be accomplished and if it is possible?

Thank you in advance
SG

Comment: I think it should work, but I would need to check. Do you have a sample application anywhere I can use to debug?